# Replacing \\u by \u in java string

Tags: java, string

I have a string which contains normal text and Unicode in between, for example "abc\ue415abc".
I want to replace all occurrences of `\\u` with `\u`.  How can I achieve this?
I used the following code but it's not working properly.

```
String s = "aaa\\u2022bbb\\u2014ccc";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    try {
        int cp = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
        m.appendReplacement(buf, "");
        buf.appendCodePoint(cp);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
}
m.appendTail(buf);
s = buf.toString();
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial string doesn't, in fact, have any double backslashes.

```
String s = "aaa\\u2022bbb\\u2014ccc";
```

yields a string that contains `aaa\u2022bbb\u2014ccc`, as `\\` is just java string-literal escaping for `\`.

If you want unicode characters: (StackOverflow21028089.java)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class StackOverflow21028089 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aaa\\u2022bbb\\u2014ccc";
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})").matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            try {
                // see example:
                // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29
                int cp = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
                char[] chars = Character.toChars(cp);
                String rep = new String(chars);
                System.err.printf("Found %d which means '%s'\n", cp, rep);
                m.appendReplacement(buf, rep);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Confused: " + e);
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(buf);
        s = buf.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

=>

```
Found 8226 which means '•'
Found 8212 which means '—'
aaa•bbb—ccc
```

If you want `aaa\u2022bbb\u2014ccc`, that's what you started with. If you meant to start with a string literal with `aaa\\u2022bbb\\u2014ccc`, that's this:

```
String s = "aaa\\\\u2022bbb\\\\u2014ccc";
```

and converting it to the one with single slashes can be as simple as @Overv's code:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\u", "\\u");
```

though since backslash has a special meaning in regex patterns *and* replacements (see [Matcher's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)) (in addition to java parsing), this should probably be:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\u", "\\\\u");
```

=>

```
aaa\u2022bbb\u2014ccc
```

Comment: happy to be of assistance!

Answer (score 3):

From API reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

You can use public

```
public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
string = string.replace("\\u", "\u");

or

String replacedString = string.replace("\\u", "\u");
```

Comment: With guava: String str = CharMatcher.anyOf("\\u").replaceFrom(yourString, "\u");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = s.replace(s.indexOf("\\u"), "\u");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `contains` method and a `replace` method in String. That being said

```
String hello = "hgjgu\udfgyud\\ushddsjn\hsdfds\\ubjn";

if(hello.contains("\\u"))
    hello.replace("\\u","\u");

System.out.println(hello);
```

It will print :- **hgjgu\udfgyud\ushddsjn\hsdfds\ubjn**

Comment: It's not working,hello.replace("\\u","\u"); gives error of invalid Unicode